# nginx regex location

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

we need to serve the static content through nginx. below is our location directive:

```
location ~ /app$ {
        root   /srv/deployments/app/build/;
        index  index.html;
    }
```

now we are expecting any thing like /app/login,/app/signup will be served by this location directive. but when we try to access /app/login we **404** error. and in addition to above location directive if we define below location directive, then it work.

```
location ~ /app/login$ {
        root   /srv/deployments/app/build/;
        index  index.html;
}
```

as there can be multiple routes, how can we define a location directive with regex so that any which match /app/.* should served by single location.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if this [link](https://serverfault.com/questions/808788/nginx-wildcard-regex-in-location-path) helps.

It suggests *(specific to that question)*

```
location ~ ^/sitename/[0-9a-z]+/index.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass phpcgi;
}
```

where:

> ^ -> Start of string
>
> [0-9a-z]+ -> matches all the characters in this range
>
> index.php$ -> end of string with index.php